# Scraping class in python outputs none or []

Tags: python, web-scraping

When I run, this code, the output is either nothing or “[]”.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer
from pytube import YouTube


responce = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(responce.text, 'html.parser')

post = soup.find(class_='style-scope ytd-app')

#post = soup.find(title='The Sky Is Pink - Official Trailer | Priyanka C J, Farhan A, Zaira W, Rohit S | Shonali B | Oct 11').get_text()

print(post)
```

Comment: Post your whole script, from top to bottom.

Comment: you're passing two classes instead of one. Also, BS will not get dynamically loaded content

Comment: @Jay this is whole program

Comment: @Marat so what changes should have to do?

Comment: @ItsAk use one class and filter by the second later (`soup.find(class_='style-scope'`). It still might not work if the content you're looking for is loaded dynamically; in this case you might have to use API or Selenium instead of BS

Comment: What exactly you want to scrap from youtube?